# Resizing a dynamically created label to fit the text inside it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a label dynamically, and then adding text to it dynamically (and the amount of text added to it will be different each time). So, the label needs to always be the same width as the text inside it.

This happens by default when creating a label in the Windows Designer. But when creating a label dynamically, it appears to be "set" at a specific width, regardless of how much text is in it (which means that it often "cuts off" some of the text).

So... any idea how I can get the dynamically created label to always stay the same width as the text inside it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it manually, you can do something like this, every time you change the text:

```
Dim g As Graphics = Label1.CreateGraphics()
Label1.Width = CInt(g.MeasureString(Label1.Text, Label1.Font).Width)
```

However, it's much easier to simply set the label's `AutoSize` property to `True` and let the label do the work for you.

```
Label1.AutoSize = True
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I guess I just assumed that the autosize property would be true by default, as it is when a label is created in the Designer.

Comment: Yes, that is odd.  I was surprised by that too.  But you'll notice in the designer that the AutoSize = True line in the properties window is bolded, which means that it's value is different than the default value.

Comment: hey accept this ans. as your problem is solved. i'm also going to ans it but i read the comment and stop.